# Fuel mileage question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

OK im trying to do my taxes due today

I drove 3034km  and my truck gets 18km/L  how much gas did I buy in liters (L)

Please help, Its been years since I had to math problems and I suck at them

Thanks

CW

Comment: $\frac{3034}{18}\approx 168.5$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find $z$ in
\begin{equation}
\left(3034 \text{ Km}\right) = \left(18 \frac{Km}{L}\right) \times (z \text{ L } )
\end{equation}

So you just do $$\displaystyle z L = \frac{3034 \text{ Km}}{18 \text{Km/L}} = \frac{3034}{18}L = 168,\overline{5} \; L\approx 168,56 \; L$$

In those calculations if you look at units of measurement it becomes immediately clear what you should do, I mean, you have Km/L and you want L, so you have to divide by Km and then reverse the result

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you saved my hide, and my sanity

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{18\text{ km}}{1 \text{ L}} \times (v \text{ L}) = 3034 \text{ km}$$ for some volume of gas $v$ in liters. Solving for $v$,
$$v\text{ L} = \frac{1 \text{ L}}{18 \text{ km}} \times (3034 \text{ km}) \approx 168.556 \text{ L}.$$

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you to you too you saved my hide, and my sanity